# Preventing Jabra speakerphone buttons from changing build-in speaker volume

Tags: audio, speakers, ms-teams

I'm using a MacBook Pro with a Jabra Speak 410 for video calls in Teams. I've generally set the build-in speaker of the MacBook as the main/active speaker in the MacOS settings so that I can mute the sound without having to mute the Jabra speaker (so that I don't enter a call with a muted speaker). This works fine, but when I increase the volume of the Jabra speaker during a call using the buttons on the Jabra, it also increases the volume of the build-in speaker of the MacBook.

Is there a way to prevent that? I want to control only the Jabra speaker with these buttons.